# modify base url using SWFAddress

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swfaddress

a question abt using SWFAddress in Flash

Lets say it is possible for a user to reach my website using this url:

www.abc.com/?from=SOME_VALUE_HERE

when i my flash website is loaded. the ?from=SOME_VALUE.. is read and it is no longer useful.

So now when i use SWFAddress.setValue("EXAMPLE")

The browser url to shows www.abc.com/?from=SOME_VALUE_HERE#/EXAMPLE

which is damn ugly.

I hope the site can shows www.abc.com/#/EXAMPLE

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to capture that address and redirect you to to `www.abc.com/`.

You could use ActionScript to communicate to javascript to reset the url using something like `window.location`

Perhaps you could also send the from variable using PUT instead of GET which would keep it from appearing in the URL.

Hope that's helpful!